# moving monthly linux files to another folder script

Tags: linux

```
sorry but I'm a beginner in Linux script commands.
```

I'm trying to automatically transfer files to another folder monthly ,on every 26th day of the existing month.(Linux system)
    I would appreciate if somebody can help!
    thank you in advance!

```
I have files with this format xxxxx_181025.txt. I want them to be moved in another folder every 26th day of month.(but only files generated for actual month, in this case October.   I need some help on how to specify that only files of existing month should be moved?


cd /actual folder
_Y='%Y'
_y='%Y'
_m='%m'
_d='%d'
TIMESTAMP=`date "+$_Y$_m$_d"`
mv xxxxx_$TIMESTAMP   /new folder/xxxxx_$TIMESTAMP 
done
```

Comment: could you provide in your question  the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)."

Comment: You can probably do this with a CRONTAB one liner... Your question, however, is very vague and does not deserve an answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
find /actual_folder -t f -mtime -26 -exec mv {} /new_folder/ \;
```

Comment: look at the error i receive: $ ./mv_files.sh
find: missing argument to `-exec'

Comment: what did you execute exactly? Did you copy the exact command, replacing only the folder names? Were there files edited in the last 26 days, that needed to be moved? (this error mentions that there were actually no files to move)

Comment: Thanks a lot, yes,the issue was with the file . now it works fine,

Comment: @Dominik if this solves your issue, I would appreciate if you accept my answer. Thank you.

Comment: I think @Ron is right. You need to start accepting answers (and upvoting everyone that helps you, even if it doesn't solve your problem. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers .